# How to publish a component written in typescript consumable as a global, commonjs, or typescript module

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, module, commonjs

I have written a simple component in typescript which has a dependency on d3. I would like to publish this component on npm and have it be usable as a global, a commonjs module, or a typescript module. The component looks something like this:

```
/// <reference types="d3" />
class MyAwesomeComponent {
  data(data: IMyDataFormat) {
    // set data, etc.
  }
  render() {
    // do stuff with d3
  }
}
interface IMyDataFormat {
  // keys/types
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` file currently looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "none",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outFile": "./dist/index.js",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

When I run `tsc` with this config, I get a file which works in the global context, so this would work for a consumer:

```
<script src="./d3.js"></script>
<script src="./my-awesome-component.js"></script>
<script>
  var chart = new MyAwesomeComponent();
  chart.data([/* ... */]);
  chart.render();
</script>
```

How do I set up my project (e.g. with alternate tsconfig files or small changes to the source files etc) so that it is consumable in a commonJS environment (i.e. webpack or browserify), as well as in a typescript project environment?

Here is what I am expecting to work for the commonJS environment:

```
const MyAwesomeComponent = require('my-awesome-component');
// this would also be fine:
const MyAwesomeComponent = require('my-awesome-component').MyAwesomeComponent;
```

Here is what I am expecting to work for the TypeScript environment:

```
import {MyAwesomeComponent, IMyDataFormat} from 'my-awesome-component';
```

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to publish your module with both `ts` and UMD `js`  scripts.

Comment: @amenadiel would you be willing to elaborate? What do I put in the module and target fields of my tsconfig, or do I need separate ones? What do I put in the `main` field of my package.json?

Comment: @amenadiel also, I don't see a way of doing this without having two versions of the source file (note that I am not `export`ing `MyAwesomeComponent` from the ts file)

Comment: I don't use typescript, but that's what I do when I publish a module both as UMD and ES6. There is a tutorial published a couple of days ago that you can check: https://60devs.com/guides/publishing-a-typescript-module-to-npm.html the package.json includes the `js` as well as the `ts` files

Comment: Appreciate you linking that guide, although my requirement of users being able to use it as a global is still not met with that approach.

Answer (score 1):

I have published a boilerplate example to npmjs.org.

- The package is called [`stackoverflow-47210046`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stackoverflow-47210046).
- I have also created a GitHub repository with the [source](https://github.com/kittaakos/stackoverflow-47210046).
- The main documentation with some steps are available there but here a few remarks too:

  - Make sure you have added `"dom"` to the libraries in the `tsconfig.json` to include them during the compilation. (This is not required in general, but the question was about consuming [`d3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3) in a boilerplate TS package.)
  - Add `"main": "lib/index"` to the `package.json`. You can see, it points to the compiled output and has no file extension.
  - Adde `"typings": "lib/index"` to the `package.json`.
  - Although the `lib` output folder is not added to version control, that will be available on npmjs.org.
  - The tests will be executed with `ts-node` so the `tsc` compilation can be omitted.
  - If you want to run your test in watch mode, execute `npm run test -- -w`.
  - If you want to run your `tsc` compiler in watch mode, execute `npm run build -- -w`.

I hope this helps, if you have any questions, just post it here, or submit a new issue on GitHub.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi @kittaakos! Thanks for the effort you put in to that boilerplate project. It looks like this wouldnt work when used as a global library (see the html code block of my question).

Comment: @AndyPerlitch, I misunderstood you then. Your "html code block" is unclear to me. How do you want to put it together? Do you have a half-ready example you can share with us? Thanks!

Comment: The html code block i am talking about is shown in my question (right after the word "consumer"). Basically it means that if a developer is not using a module loading system or a transpiler, he/she should be able to include my library and it will just get added to the `window` object as a global. In your example project this is not the case. I believe what I want is UMD output, but when I specify umd in the module setting of tsconfig, it does not correctly attach my class to the window as I expect it to do. Again, thanks for looking into this! I'll push the real project to github and link it..

Comment: I see your point, thanks for the clarification! I look forward seeing the example.

Comment: To add: I am using my fork of the `fmd` module in the `build.js` file, which gets called in the `npm run build` script (see top-level package.json). I still am lacking two things: (1) the ability to have multiple files of source code and still have a single built file generated in dist, and (2) I have to manually update the declaration file created by `tsc`, `dist/skills-barchart.d.ts`, which does not work in its generated form; I have to modify it to look like `dist/skills-barchart-class.d.ts`. I know this is a lot, thanks for looking.

Comment: Hi! You need to remove `outFile` from your `tsconfig` and specify `outDir` instead to solve your 1st problem. It may solve your 2nd problem, but i'm not sure..